# How to Transfer SSMS "Font & Color" settings from one machine to another?

Tags: sql-server

This is a Quality of Life question. I have low vision. Accordingly I use High Contrast fonts. When I do this all the keyword highlighting in SSMS gets reset to the same color. For years, I have dutifully gone into SSMS -> Tools -> Options, and in the "Options" dialog, under Environment\Fonts And Colors, gone through and configured all my keyword colors.

It's tedious though, and I hop amongst a lot of servers. Most of them I turn on high contrast, but don't set up the query analyzer with color settings. I would love to know where SSMS stores the options when I set them. Is it a config file? or a registry key?

I'm looking for some way I can generate a "Golden Standard" copy of my settings, and then import it into a new machine when I set it up.
Or in the case of today, when I find my fonts have reset back to the default "Same Color with no keyword highlighting" after toggling "Hight Contrast" off, and then back on again, because I had to do a presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron Bertrand wrote about this a while back that may be helpful. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/making-ssms-pretty-my-dark-theme

SSMS -> Tools -> Import and Export Settings... -> Export selected environment settings -> Select your desired options and save the .vssettings file.

Then import as needed.

Comment: this is a link only answer, please add some content

Comment: exercise for the OP.  fixed

Comment: 100% the answer. I tested it, copying settings from an already configured workstation to one of the servers Thanks so much for the answer! 

Almost 20 years I've been looking. Not that hard of course, 5 to 10 minutes once a year or so, because there was always a more pressing need on my time. But I hope the format of my subject makes it easier for the next guy like me to find.

Comment: @InCrypt_ You should accept this answer if it’s the one you want.